# failed to set __main__.__loader__ in Python

Tags: python

When running any Python script (by double clicking a .py file on Windows 7) I'm getting a `Python: failed to set __main__.__loader__` error message. What to do?

**More details:**

- The scripts work on other machines.
- The only version of Python installed on the machine on which the scripts don't work is 3.2.
- I get the same error when trying to run the script from the Windows shell (cmd).
- Here's an example for the content of a file named "hey.py" that I failed to run on my machine:

  `print('hey')`

Comment: Can you run with `C:\Python32\python -v <scriptfile>` and see if any weird modules come up? I think some module must be installing a broken import hook.

Comment: I was getting the same issue with python 3.3.0.

Comment: @snakile, is your Windows7 - home edition? I think that home edition, which has problems with other languages is a problem. If it is not, try to install language pack that is in your filepath.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. Turns out it was because the file was stored in a directory with a name not in English (Hebrew in my case).
Make sure the path to the file contains only English letters.

http://bugs.python.org/issue16218

Comment: In my computer - all languanges are working, except Russian. Hebrew also works. It has something to do with cmd -- you can not print in not-working language. Windows-7-64.

Comment: Why on earth having some Hebrew as part of the path still causes problems in such a modern unicoded era? Haven't the Jewish people suffered enough?

Comment: Are you kidding? I can't believe that. I just can't. (I know someone already said something similar but I don't like to involve Jewish in the story. That's just some shit that still doesn't handle all UTF-8 characters properly even after 2013. What a pity)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.  Like mottyg1 said, it happens when the python script is run from a directory containing non-english characters.  I can't change the directory name though, and my python script needed to be in the directory in order to perform manipulations on the filenames.  So my workaround was simply to move the script to a different folder and then pass in the directory containing the files to be changed.

So to be clear, the problem is only when the directory containing the python file has non-english characters, but python can still handle such characters in its functions, at least as far as I've been able to tell.

Comment: I don't seem to have the problem on Linux. I'd blame Windows instead of Python.