# Python script doesn't work under path containing Chinese characters

Tags: windows, python-3.3

I wrote a script in Python 3.3 which was installed on Windows 8. Here's the problem: I can run it by double-clicking it when its path is composed of English characters, such as "E:\test\myscript.py".

But if there are some Chinese characters in its path, such as "E:\测试\myscript.py", it doesn't work when I double-click it, and there is an error:

> "python: failed to set **main**._*loader*_".

How can I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It seems like it is a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696151/python-failed-to-set-main-loader